# What tool is used to cut back the outer jacket and dielectric of a coaxial cable?

Tags: tools, coax

I would like to assemble a few SMA connectors on 0.086" semirigid coaxial cable.
Here is an image of the assembly instructions on one such part (Amphenol 901-9723).

[image]

As you can see, the outer jacket of the cable and dielectric must be cut back by dimenion **a**.
What tool is suitable for cutting/scoring a controlled length the outer jacket and dielectric of the cable without damaging the inner conductor?

I'm willing to spend up to around $1,000 on a tool set.

Comment: A coaxial cable stripper.

Comment: fancier than a copper plumbing cutter? budget?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Added budget to post. Note that I'm working with 0.086" cable, so a copper plumbing cutter probably won't cut it.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/AG-Cables-Stripper-Stripping-Satellite/dp/B007F1WBUY

Comment: When I worked up to 6GHZ with high return loss, Motolora and I use hand tools with training for prototypes. Since I dont know what your RL*GHz needs are, I suspect from your profile you want then precision pencil sharpener kind for a couple grand as disturbance of Ro/Ri ratio affects the above figure of merit.

Answer (score 1):

To make a clean work use a coaxial cable stripper: you may find one on aliexpress or rfsupplier site in 5 minutes. They are built for a range of diameters: yours should fit well; I will post a picture of mine when back home end of week. The price is indeed less than 10$ and I don't think you need anything more expensive. Otherwise a cutter with a sharp new blade will do the job, because you do not have to cut sleeve and braid at different lengths here, just cut through the dielectric neatly to the inner conductor.

How to cut to size: cut it slightly abundant and then trim the inner conductor to size after some trial and error gently pushing into the spring contact. You can shape as hinted the tip to 90° or so, to help centering inside the spring contact and to apply force evenly.

Soldering: it is clearly said not to apply excessive heat not to distort/melt the dielectric. Well, the cable may bring away the heat so the soldering iron shall be about 40W (or up to 60W used gently and wisely) for a good result. Apply some flux paste to the metallic cable shield depending on the material: silvered copper or brass does not need it, otherwise it is not doing any harm. I am using colophony in alcohol.

You cannot rework, it usually does not give good results. If the solder joint surface is not even, you may use a fine grinder gently removing the tin alloy in excess.

Comment: Thank you, +1. I made a mistake in the post: I said 0.086" where I should have said 0.034". The strippers I've found don't seem suitable for the smaller size. Are you aware of strippers for the smaller size cables?

Comment: That small?! ok, better if you do a work by hand with a sharp new blade in the cutter, and a few attempts to limit the force you apply. The inner conductor is very very small then. While cutting you can slide the blade gently to reduce the amount of force needed.
The cheap cutter I had in mind is this (http://www.rfsupplier.com/coax-coaxial-universal-stripping-tool-p-2163.html?cPath=28): good, but too big.
I shall reduce also the watt rating of the soldering iron not to melt the dielectric.

Answer (score 0):

On the bench, I always used a scalpel to score the outer, then bent to and fro until it fractured along the score. This leaves a raised burr around the end of the jacket, which may need to be removed with a file or abrasive paper.

I am sure there are proper tools for doing it in production, the recommendation for which would be off topic on this forum.

Comment: Hmmm.  Used to use my pocket knife instead of a scalpel.  Otherwise the same.

Comment: @JRE you used a pocket knife to cut 0.086" coax?

Comment: My pockey knife is usually sharp enough to shave with.  A scalpel isn't much sharper.

Answer (score 0):

This is for semi rigid coax only.

You can make a jig for endstops with this DIY solution for prototypes.  I used this method for 6GHz then  tested after on VNA.

[image]

Comment: How thin of a cable have you done with this?

Comment: this says 1/8th but not what I used years ago, you can do 0.086" semi-rigid coax rotating and turning dial just  a bit each few revs till smooth. cheap DIY , or get the expensive " pencil sharpener" version if you dont have the touch. Then exacto on dielectric then comb puller or by hand.